# How do I disable a particular script depending on media query?

Tags: javascript

Been struggling with this one, can't get it to work. I only want this script to work for desktop.
Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#scroll_top').hide();
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {}
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 1000) { // If page is scrolled more than 50px
            $('#scroll_top').fadeIn(300); // Fade in the arrow
        } else {
            $('#scroll_top').fadeOut(300); // Else fade out the arrow
        }
    });
    $('#scroll_top').click(function() { // When arrow is clicked
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0 // Scroll to top of body
        }, 500);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by desktop? like computers ?

If yes add the if condition below :

```
if( !(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ) {
 // Your code
}
```

The condition bellow spot all the smartphone or tablet browser.

```
/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

The "!" before the condition make it spot all the others : so computers ones.

You can also try with window width if the window width is lower than 1024px you can assume that the device would be a tablet or a smartphone.

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 1024){
    //your code
}
```

Feel free to ask if needed.

Comment: mmmm!!! weird. I've edited my answer to add width condition, maybe it will works better. let me know

Comment: Thanks very much pal. Unfortunately not working, either one. Whyyyy oh whyyyy

Comment: Plus when I use this then the arrow does not appear after scrolling but it's there from the start

Comment: I 've actulally made a mistake on my code. the 1024 should not be between quotes cause the result of window innerWidth is not a string but a number. I've made the correction on my answer. Now it suppose to work. Let me know

Comment: Thanks but still nope

Comment: Ok this is really weird, you should have an error on your console that make bug your script.

Answer (score 0):

I would test for window size, not device type.  Testing for window size is more accurate than testing for device and besides, if someone does have a big screen with 15 thousand (yes, I'm exaggerating on purpose:) ) windows open and resized very small, would you want this script to run?  Probably not.

BUT . . .

I recognize this script as a "scroll to top" buttons script, perhaps you DO want it to work on smaller devices, just with a smaller image?  I personally find them very useful as long as they are sized small enough to not block content . .   just my 2 cents,.  I'm sure you know your website better than me.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you :)) Yes, I have considered it and in my case (not too many items) I believe that scrolling is a much faster way to get back to the top instead of an expensive click.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to depend on css media query you can add 3 invisible elements to your HTLM and then test if the display is set to block.

Add thes elements to your footer

```
#isMobile,#isTablet{ 
     Display:none;
}
@media (max-width: 500px){
    #isMobile{
     Display: block;
    }
 }
@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 1024px){
    #isTablet{
     Display: block;
    }
 }
```

Js

```
If( $("#isTablet").css("display") == "block") {
// do code
}
```

I don't guarantee my code works but you should get the basic idea how to use css media query in js. This way if you change breakpoint sizes you won't need to update javascript.

On other hand you can always do a simple window width test with

```
if( $(window).width() > 1024 ){
    //do code
}
```